# Convert all characters except a set of characters to whitespace in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a set of characters that are defined as valid characters. Let me define the valid string by the following regexp:

> ^[a-zA-Z0-9\ .-_]+$

(alphanumeric, space, dot, dash and underscore)

The question is that given a column containing a lot of invalid characters, how I can run an update to convert each invalid character to one space? And then possibly convert consequent spaces to one space?

I cannot run several replace commands because there are a lot of possible invalid characters. So I expect a regexp solution.

Currently, I am doing the task in Java (after exporting the table to tsv format). But I want a MySQL approach.

Comment: I know the regex for identifying the invalid strings, but I want to convert all the invalid characters in these strings to white space.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql). In my experience as it is not possible in `MySQL` you can switch to `Postgres` or pull data into another language (Perl is a good one for this), and covert there and re-import and you are always better off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MySQL version supports it, [create a function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION my_func_1 (str TEXT)
  RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
  DECLARE ret TEXT DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE chr TEXT DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
  WHILE i < (LENGTH(str) + 1) DO
    SET chr = SUBSTRING(str, i, 1);
    IF chr REGEXP '[-a-zA-Z0-9\\_.]'
      THEN SET ret = CONCAT(ret, chr);
    ELSE
      SET ret = CONCAT(ret, ' ');
    END IF;
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
  WHILE ret LIKE '%  %' DO
    SET ret = REPLACE(ret, '  ', ' ');
  END WHILE;
  RETURN TRIM(ret);
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Test it a bit:

`SELECT my_func_1('$a-B\\?!=01._%');` > `a-B\ 01._`

and update with `SET col = my_func_1(col)`

---

If not needed anymore:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS my_func_1;
```

Also I changed your regex a bit as `-` indicates a range, if between characters in a class or is `.-_` intended? Then modify the pattern.

Comment: Perfect! I found some other versions on the Internet, but did have problems in converting some of the characters. 
In this version, we just have to define the regexp inside the function.

Comment: @Alisa Great, it works for your task, glad could have helped :)